# Group by to create a vertical coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, coalesce

I have this query.

```
select transaction, bbk, sbk, obk, ibk
from
(
  select 
    transaction, 
    case when "'BBK'" = 1 then country end bbk,
    case when "'SBK'" = 1 then country end sbk,
    case when "'OBK'" = 1 then country end obk,
    case when "'IBK'" = 1 then country end ibk  
  from (
    select 
    regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 1) as transaction,
    regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 2) as code,
    regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 3) as country
    from Table1 t)
  pivot 
  ( 
    --case when count(code) = 1 then 
    count(code)
    for code in ('BBK','SBK','OBK','IBK')
  )  
)
group by transaction, bbk, sbk, obk, ibk
order by transaction
```

The results, as you can see in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caf32/73)

```
00004719    US  US  (null)  (null)
00004719    (null)  (null)  GB  (null)
00004719    (null)  (null)  (null)  DE
```

Show multiple lines per transaction.  I would like to alter the query so that only 1 line per transaction occurs.

Essentially coalescing vertically the nulls in the other records to achieve:

```
00004719    US  US  GB  DE
```

How might this be done?

Comment: Use this as a nested query and group over the transaction column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caf32/77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what `pivot` is for:

```
select 
  transaction, 
  "'BBK'",
  "'SBK'",
  "'OBK'",
  "'IBK'"
from (
  select 
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 1) as transaction,
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 2) as code,
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 3) as country
  from Table1 t)
pivot 
( 
  MAX(country) for code in ('BBK','SBK','OBK','IBK')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the results of your query and group over the transaction column again:

```
with x as (
select transaction, bbk, sbk, obk, ibk
from
(
      select 
        transaction, 
        case when "'BBK'" = 1 then country end bbk,
        case when "'SBK'" = 1 then country end sbk,
        case when "'OBK'" = 1 then country end obk,
        case when "'IBK'" = 1 then country end ibk  
      from (
        select 
        regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 1) as transaction,
        regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 2) as code,
        regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 3) as country
        from Table1 t)
      pivot 
      ( 
        --case when count(code) = 1 then 
        count(code)
        for code in ('BBK','SBK','OBK','IBK')
      )  
  )
group by transaction, bbk, sbk, obk, ibk
) select
transaction, max(bbk), max(sbk), max(obk), max(ibk)
from x
group by transaction
order by transaction;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caf32/77)

Edit:

or equivalently, just group by transaction in the original query:

```
select 
  transaction, 
  max(case when "'BBK'" = 1 then country end) bbk,
  max(case when "'SBK'" = 1 then country end) sbk,
  max(case when "'OBK'" = 1 then country end) obk,
  max(case when "'IBK'" = 1 then country end) ibk  
from (
  select 
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 1) as transaction,
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 2) as code,
  regexp_substr("col_a", '[^~]+', 1, 3) as country
  from Table1 t)
pivot ( 
  count(code)
  for code in ('BBK','SBK','OBK','IBK')
)  
group by 
  transaction
order by 
  transaction;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/caf32/87)

Comment: Why do it via COUNT and then invent something around it when you can do MAX(country) inside the PIVOT?

Comment: @Bulat can't argue with that.

Comment: original solution sometimes complicates things.

Comment: If you edit it I will be able to revert my vote, now it is locked